# How to save Json data to mongoose in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The below is the route am using to receive the json data but the problem is i don't know how i can save it to mongoose

```
router.post('/payment, async(req, res)=>{
    
    var secret  = secret;

    var event = req.body;

    console.log(event)

    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

So how can i save the event am receiving to mongoose?

Comment: i used data:{status: type: String}} on my model and i also used data:{success: type: String}} also not working on  my post route i used data:{status: req.body.status} and i also tried data:{success": req.body.success} and no one is working. Please i don't know what to do again

Answer (score 0):

You need to define model in mongoose and import it to file with your function. Then your route should look like this.

```
router.post('/payment, async(req, res)=>{
    
    var secret  = secret;

    var event = req.body; 

    const { variable_1, variable_2 } = req.body

    const newEvent = modelName({
        variable_1:variable_1,
        variable_2:variable_2
    })
 
    newEvent.save()
      .then(event => res.json(event))
    console.log(event)

    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: what about the var event  = req.body? should i add it to the variables or what

Comment: I only end up getting just the event id nothing else

Comment: I don't understand you want to save it to database or what? If yes you need to define model if you want save just id define model with some variable name and type string. Destructure variable  from req.body and pass it down in newEvent({modelVariableName:req.body.yourIdName}).

Comment: Not working . its just returning nothing.

Comment: Try it now. I`have the same type of model in my db and route and it works. Maybe you don`t pass variable in form at req.body. Now I`ve changed it to const message. I`ve also added message for your resoponse at end. You can use it if you need.

Comment: I did that but am not getting the correct data. data:{status:"success"} this is what i want not data:{success: "success"}. So if i use data:{status: req.body.status} it will say status undefined and if i shoud set it as data:{status: "status"} it will also give me status instead of success that i want .    The req.body am receiving is like this {event: "charge.success", data:{ status: "success", reference: "123564" , customer:{ name: "dan", email: "dan@me.com"}}.

Comment: So that is exactly what am receiving and i want to save some of this data to mongoose . Th event which i set to event: req.body.event on my post route is working fine as am getting the correct data which is "charge.success". So please assist me in getting this done . i really appreciate your assistance so far

Answer (score 0):

Model.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const yourNameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     id:{
        type:String
     }, 
     data:{
          status:{
                  type:String        
          },
          reference:{
              type:String
          },
          customer:{
              name:{
                  type:String
              },
              email:{
                  type:String
              }
          }
          
     }
})

const name = mongoose.model('modelName',yourNameSchema,'collectionName')

module.exports = name
```

your route file

```
router.post('/payment, async(req, res)=>{
    
    var secret  = secret

    var event = req.body

    const { id } = req.body
    const { status, reference } = req.body.data
    const { name, email } = req.body.data.customer

    const newEvent = modelName({
        id:id,
        data:{
             status:status, 
             reference:reference
             customer:{
                 name:name,
                 email:email
             }
        }   

    })

    newEvent.save()
      .then(event => res.json(event))
    console.log(event)

    res.sendStatus(200)
    res.json(message:"success")
});
```

Comment: Okay thanks I can get that now but how can  I get something like this data:{ status: "success"}. How can I add that to my model and also to the post route. I tried this on my model data:{status:type: String}} but I don't know how to add that to the post route. The ones I tried are not working

Comment: This is the req.body am receiving {event: "event.success", data:{status: "success", reference: "12345", customer:{ name: "dan", email: "dan@me.com"}} . Now am able to save the event successfully using , event: req.body.event on the post route. but am not getting anything when i use data:{ status: req.body.status} the result is telling me status is undefined. the right result i should be getting suppose to be data:{status: "success"}.

Comment: So that is exactly what am receiving and i want to save some of this data to mongoose . Th event which i set to event: req.body.event on my post route is working fine as am getting the correct data which is "charge.success". So please assist me in getting this done . i really appreciate your assistance so far

Comment: I`ve updated code. If you get undefined just check it it console maybe you don`t pass value and its undefined.

Comment: I did that but am not getting the correct data. data:{status:"success"} this is what i want not data:{success: "success"}. So if i use data:{status: req.body.status} it will say status undefined and if i shoud set it as data:{status: "status"} it will also give me status instead of success that i want . The req.body am receiving is like this {event: "charge.success", data:{ status: "success", reference: "123564" , customer:{ name: "dan", email: "dan@me.com"}}

Comment: Becouse it is req.body.data.status so that is why is undefined. If you not mean a status of request like 200. I have destructure your data in code. It should save in that way you want. data:{status:"success"}

Comment: Thanks so much is now working successfully. I'm trying to find reference and email using this Payment.find({data:{reference: req.body.reference}} and Payment.find({data:{customer:{email: req.body.email}) but they are not working as they are returning empty array. Please how can i achieve that?

Comment: Beacouse it not match any. You should use Payment.find({"data.customer":req.body.email}) Payment.find({"data.refenrence":req.body.reference})

Comment: Data reference also returns empty array? When you use only find method have you have filled array? I do mistake at second should be data.customer.email. If it not important you can filter array using javascript filter method

Comment: Yes data reference also returns empty array. data.customer.email : req.body.email , also returns empty arrays

Comment: When I use only Payment.find({}) I get all the data, I have filled array

Comment: You use exactly Payment.find({"data.refenrence":req.body.reference}).toArray without "" It won't work also add toArray. I have the same route and mine works. You can use in javascript on whole array array.filter(reference => reference === that variable or value you look) it will return filtered array.

Comment: Payment.find({"data.reference": req.body.reference}).toArrray, is returning undefined

Comment: I don't know why. I have the same in my projects and it working. Try to only find and filter it. array.filter(reference => reference === that variable or value you look). It's working fast

Comment: How can I do that please . Should I do Payment.find({"data.reference": req.body.reference}) then what next ? Where should I add the array.filter(reference=>reference=== since is reference am looking for what should be here) . Please could you use my model to give me clear example on how I can do that

Comment: Do only find() and apply filter method in your script file where you take data back. Look on YouTube how to solve it

Comment: I did this Payment.find({}, {"data.reference": 1}) which am getting correctly but when I do something like  Payment.find({}, {"data.customer.email":1}) I got something like this {data:{customer:[Object], _id:60dv557gh67}} why am I getting Object instead of the email ?